# Unable to edit link on CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, ckeditor

Just like the headline says, I am unable to edit links on CKEditor. I have a fresh installation and when I type in a text that I want to mark as a link, the link pop up opens with all the fields and buttons but they don't work - with exception of the Browse server button.

They are not even in disabled color, they just don't work! Drop-down menus don't open and text areas/fields are not editable! I have tried to update with the latest jquery version, I tested without other plugins that also use javascript and would might get in conflict but it still does not work. Yes, I have also tested with a clean cache! The only way to edit a link is to do it on source mode.

So, any suggestions on what the problem is?

**Here is the config.js:**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

       config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
       config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
       config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
       config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
       config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
       config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';


    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons, provided by the standard plugins, which we don't
    // need to have in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Subscript,Superscript';

    // Se the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;pre';

    // Make dialogs simpler.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;';

    config.language = 'sv';

    config.extraPlugins = 'format,horizontalrule,templates';

    CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;

    config.allowedContent = true;

};
```

Comment: JSFiddle? You config looks OK.

Comment: What should I do there?

Comment: [Create a sample that works so the issue can be reproduced](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Any messages in the browser developer console?

Comment: @Nenotlep yes, 2 and both say the exakt same thing: TypeError: d.browser is undefined - what does this mean?

Comment: Sounds a lot like that error is preventing JS from functioning properly. Try to debug and get rid of it. It's very hard to guess what is causing it. Try to create a minimal set where the problem happens to reproduce it and to narrow down what causes it. Remove features and plugins and such one by one until you find what is causing it and then if you can't fix it we might be of more help

Comment: @Nenotlep followed ur lead and came to the conclusion that the addition of a modernizr.js would solve my issue but it did not. I now have this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefinedjquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js:25 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 n.extend.mapjquery.min.js:2 n.fn.n.mapjquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js:24 d.fn._scrollablejquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js:36 d.fn.scrollTojquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js:9 ijquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js:9 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:3 n.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3 r.handle

Answer (score 2):

This post might be helpful: 
**[CKEditor + Magnific Popup. Link editing does not work](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1147)**

Here is one more example (based on **CKEditor5**):

```js
let theEditor;

ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {

    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote']
  })
  .then(editor => {
    theEditor = editor;

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

```css
.ck-editor__editable {
  min-height: 150px;
}

body {
  --ck-z-default: 100;
  --ck-z-modal: calc( var(--ck-z-default) + 999);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea name="content" id="editor">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameta quam, nec bibendum neq</p>
          </textarea>

        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

CKeditor Link is not working in modal, below solution solved the issue

```css
.ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-balloon-panel, .ck.ck-balloon-panel.ck-rounded-corners {
    z-index: 10055 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have solved it by setting:

```
 .ck.ck-balloon-panel {
        z-index: 1050 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Penny-Liu  was right with her link. It has to do with a conflict between models (bootstrap, magnificpopup, and possibly others).

For magnific pop-up the solution is easy:

```
$.magnificPopup.instance._onFocusIn = function(e) {
  if( $(e.target).hasClass('ck-input') ) {
     return true;
  } 
  $.magnificPopup.proto._onFocusIn.call(this,e);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code where your modal form is:

```
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () { };
```